# How to show many data lines with Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting

How could I show many lines with data, using `Manipulate`?

```
Manipulate[
 Print["Number...Square...Cube"];
 Do[Print[z, "...", z^2, "....", z^3], {z, 1, zmax}];
 PieChart[Table[i^3, {i, 1, zmax}], ChartLabels -> Range[zmax]]
 , {zmax, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}}]
```

I see the `PieChart` inside the CDF-place, but the data is showed outside, after the Square of CDF.

I´m interesetd too in Show the text of the PieChart greater, and with a label of the data, for example 9 and under the 9.... (21%)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use functions like [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Row.html), [`Column`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Column.html) and [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html) rather than `Print`. For example:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   TableForm[
    Table[{z, z^2, z^3}, {z, 1, zmax}], 
    TableHeadings -> {None, {"Number", "Square", "Cube"}}],
   PieChart[Table[i^3, {i, 1, zmax}], ChartLabels -> Range[zmax], ImageSize -> 200]
   }],
 {zmax, Range[16]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I like very much your solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Manipulate[
 lst = Table[{z, z^2, z^3}, {z, 1, zmax, 1}];
 Column[{
   Grid[Prepend[lst, {"Number...", "Square...", "Cube...."}]],
   PieChart[Table[i^3, {i, 1, zmax}], ChartLabels -> Range[zmax]]
   }], {zmax, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
   16}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I like your solution.